# Can I debug a dependent assembly from a powershell module

Tags: powershell, debugging, visual-studio-code, .net-standard, powershell-core

I have a project it has two (or more) projects.

For example:

```
Shared.Standard
Utility.PoSH
```

The second is a PowerShell binary module that depends on the `Shared.Standard` class library/project/assembly.

Can I debug the `Shared.Standard` library while I execute commands from the compiled module in a PowerShell session? I'm particularly curious about required config in vscode.

Comment: Did you ever find out if this was possible? I'm trying to do something similar but don't now where to get started.

Comment: No, I didn't get anywhere.  I would start with the following if I was going to try again: https://it-trials.craigchamberlain.it/debugging/debug-someone-elses-nuget-package